# Different outputs while forking process

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pid

I'm getting different number of outputs in the below attached code. Sometimes it prints 6 PID's or sometimes 8 PID's. **Desired output is 7 PID's**. Though sometimes I'm able to get 7 PID's.

**Process tree:**

```
          A
       /  |  \
      B   C   D
     / \  |
    E   F G
```

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int pidb=-1;
    if(fork()==0) pidb=getpid();
    fork();
    if(getppid()!=pidb) fork(); 
    printf("%d\n",getpid());
}
```

**Note:** Assume that the fork call will be successful.

[update]

We need to achieve it using 3 fork calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int pidb=-1;
        if(fork()==0) pidb=getpid();
        fork();
        if(getppid()!=pidb) fork();
        wait(NULL);  // Wait for all child process
        printf("%d\n",getpid());
    }
```

This is what you want.
This will print 7 pid of those 7 process

---

Final process tree would be like this

```
          A (First fork) 
       /    \
      B      c   (2nd fork) 
     / \     / \
    D   E    F  G  (3rd fork)
   / \  / \  /\   | 
   1  2 3 4  5 6  7
```

Comment: What is the need to include a wait() call??

Comment: @sidkamaria if you will not wait in main process then when your child process is going on and main process terminate then its child will also get terminated so your print msg will not come

Comment: a pid is defined as a 'pid_t', not as an int.

Comment: exiting the parent process while the child process is still running can produce a zombie process of the child  so each process that performs a 'fork()' needs to wait for its' child process to exit.

Comment: the getppid() and getpid() and fork() system calls require #include <sys/types..h> and #include <unistd.h>    Without those #includes, the compiler will assume all values and return types are 'int'   And without those #includes, the compiler (you are enabling all warnings, yes) will complain about using those default parameter and return types

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the required header files. to use `fork()`, you need to have

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
```

With this, I'm able to get the expected output.

That said, in your code, it seems you don't wait for completion of child processes.

You need to have a [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) call in your parent process to wait till child has finished execution.

Also, it's not `void main()`, actually `int main(void)`. a `return 0` at the end is good practice.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why would it print 8 outputs even though there is an 'if' statement.